# Create report which shows Opportunties in Stage X for longer than Y days

Tags: reporting, custom-report-type

I would like to create a report that will show Opportunities that are stuck in stages 5-8 for longer 5 days (in each stage, not collectively)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Opportunity History Report displays the duration a stage was in once it is changed but does not have anything for the current stage. You could create your own field by doing the following:

1. Create a Date Field on the Opportunity object.
2. Create a Workflow rule that fires when the Stage is changed to populate new date field.
3. Create a Formula to calculate the number of days between the date field and today.

There is an idea out on the IdeaExchange so vote it up:

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BovX

Comment: What workflow rule would be suitable to update the field on Stage updates?

Comment: I would use is created and everytime it's edited and then use a formula to check if the stage changed "ISCHANGED( StageName )"